# Url is unreachable in facebook comments

Tags: facebook, comments

as the topic, I have tried so many ways such as

1. change app domain and site url but it doesn't work
2. debug at
   https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fplayshare.net23.net%2Fplaylist.php%3Fid%3D550830884
   and it shows me

   > Critical Errors That Must Be Fixed
   >       URL Blocked:Could not scrape URL because it has been blocked.
3. add some opengraph tag but it doesn't work

in my code

```
<fb:comments
href="http://playshare.net23.net/playlist.php?id=<?php echo $fid;?>"
num_posts="3"
width="720">
</fb:comments> 
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=360914253960714&amp;xfbml=1"></script>
```

anyones have a solution please tell me, 
very thanks

Comment: If that's a free hosting site, it may be blocked entirely regardless of which domain name you use

Comment: @Igy yes, it's a free hosting site but in addition i try other page in the same domain such as playshare.net23.net/comment2.php?id=550830884 it works fine so it cause a little confuse for me.